# Accessing loop control variable inside lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, reference

I am using the following code, with the intention of accessing `i` inside of the lambda:

```
for (int i = 0; i < FLAGS_threads; i++) {
  threads[i] = std::thread([=, &client, &tn, &i, &families, &rows, &cols, &val
                          ] {
```

What I found is that in each iteration, the value of `i` inside the lambda is `FLAGS_threads`.

What is the proper syntax for achieving my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capture *by value*.

Capturing by reference have two problems.

The first is that all threads will share the same variable, changing it in one thread (even the "main" thread) changes it in all threads. That means when the loop is over its value will be equal to `FLAGS_threads` (in your case).

The second problem is much worse: The variable `i` is *local* inside the loop! Keeping a reference to it will lead to *undefined behavior* if you use it after the loop have ended.

Unless you actually *need* to, then always capture by value.

---

And if you need to capture that many variables by reference as you use in your code, perhaps you should default to capture-by-reference and then add an exception for the `i` variable?

Like

```
[&, i]() { ... }
```

But keep in mind what I said above. Do you *really* need to capture all whose variables by reference?

Another tip: Keep your lambdas small. Large lambdas tend to be hard to read and follow, and therefore hard to maintain. Perhaps it's better to use a function? Or to call a function in the lambda?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I got my code working.

Comment: @Ted If an answer is helpful, it's customary to give it a positive vote. If it solves your problem then accepting it would be nice. Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) (and [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help) in general) to learn about the etiquette of StackOverflow.